# Creating point, popup, circle, convert coordinates issues (Arcgis JS 4.6 API)

Tags: javascript, gis, geometry, arcgis

I want to do some simple things on a basemap project.

- Such as creating a circle.
- Creating a popup when click on created point.
- Converting lat long to x y

How can I do these things?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular *[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* Do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: My codes https://github.com/xennnnnnn/project1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var pt = new Point({
      longitude: 99.909550,
      latitude: 99.751906

  });



  var lineAtt = {
      Name: "fill",
      Owner: "fill",
      Length: "999 km"
  };

    // Create a graphic and add the geometry and symbol to it
  var pointGraphic = new Graphic({
      geometry: pt,
      symbol: markerSymbol,
      attributes: lineAtt,
      popupTemplate: { // autocasts as new PopupTemplate()
          title: "{Name}",
          content: [{
              type: "fields",
              fieldInfos: [{
                  fieldName: "Name"
              }, {
                  fieldName: "Owner"
              }, {
                  fieldName: "Length"
              }]
          }]
      }
  });
```

I found the solution that open popup while clicking the created point.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same problem however for me it still does not work.. Could you please add a jsfiddle?